# List Column Type in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
type Competition struct {
    ID           uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
    UserID       uint64
    Title        string  `gorm:"size:100;not null" validate:"required,min=10,max=100"`
    Description  string  `gorm:"size:5000;not null" validate:"required,min=100,max=5000"`
    Latitude     float64 `gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    Longitude    float64 `gorm:"not null" validate:"required"`
    Address      string  `gorm:"size:1000;not null" validate:"required,max=1000"`
    StartingDate string  `gorm:"not null" validate:"required,min=10,max=10"`
    StartingTime string  `gorm:"not null" validate:"required,min=5,max=5"`
    EndingTime   string
    Images       []string
    CreatedAt    uint64 `gorm:"autoCreateTime"`
    UpdatedAt    uint64 `gorm:"autoUpdateTime:milli"`

    // relationships
    Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:participant;"`
}
```

I am using postgresql and need to add list data type column but []string is not working and generating exception while migrating models to db.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an array of integers as a data type in a Gorm Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256680/adding-an-array-of-integers-as-a-data-type-in-a-gorm-model)

Answer (score 1):

As metalisticpain stated through a post link that you need to use [`pq.StringArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray) type postgres for it to work

Just change `Images` Field as below

```golang
Images    pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]"`
```

Don't forget to import `github.com/lib/pq` library which contains [`pq.StringArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray) implementation

And make sure while inserting data you wrap it with [`pq.Array`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#Array)

Comment: /home/arslanhaider/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.3.4/migrator.go:143
[error] unsupported data type: &[]

Comment: got this error while migrating

Comment: @ArslanHaiderSherazi please check the updated answer and let me know if any issue

Comment: ERROR: type "string[]" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42704)

Comment: @ArslanHaiderSherazi sorry for the delay I was busy in work answer updated with correct type.